# Using parent references

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm using libgit2sharp and I'd like to get a `Commit` object representing something like `HEAD~10`. I tried `repo.Lookup("HEAD~10")`, but that doesn't work:

> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2Exception: An error was raised by libgit2. Class = GITERR_REFERENCE (-1).
>    The given reference name is not valid
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.Success(Int32 result, Boolean allowPositiveResult)
>       at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.Resolve[T](String name)
>       at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Lookup(String shaOrReferenceName, GitObjectType type, LookUpOptions lookUpOptions)
>       at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Lookup(String shaOrReferenceName, GitObjectType type)
>       at libgit_tmp.Program.Main(String[] args)

I realize I could do the same by something like the following code, but I'd still prefer it if I could specify the reference this way. Is there some way to do it? If not, is it a limitation of libgit2sharp or of libgit2?

```
var commit = repo.Head.Tip;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    commit = commit.Parents.First();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, LibGit2Sharp isn't able to accept parameters following the **[rev-parse revision-specification syntax](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)**.

The proposed workaround is currently the best possible implementation. It's fully compliant with the documentation which states

> A suffix ~<n> to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the <n>th generation ancestor of the named commit object, following only the first parents.

However, a feature has been recently **[merged](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/684)** in the development branch of libgit2 which may cover "retrieving parent references" need and beyond.

A nice API is now **[available](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/revparse.h#L23-32)** and makes possible to retrieve a concrete git object from a revparse textual specification. In order to get a quick peek at its usage, the tests are available **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/refs/revparse.c)**.

Binding this API and making it widely available to LibGit2Sharp is yet to be done.